# Where is the forward delete button in iPhone’s keyboard?

Tags: iphone, keyboard

Where is the left-to-right delete button in iPhone’s keyboard? We have backspace but where is Delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "forward delete" key (as it's often called) on the iPhone. The same is true on the Mac.

On the Mac you can hold down the <kbd>Fn</kbd> (Function) key and press the Delete key to get forward deletion, but there's nothing on the iPhone.

Comment: Full size keyboards do have a delete button.

Comment: @andersmoldin Valid, though I believe my point stands: No Mac ships with an extended keyboard by default, MacBooks all have the standard keyboard, and if you go to the Apple site and click on Mac accessories, then keyboard, they refer exclusively to the standard keyboard. You have to actually click on the little ad-like link at the bottom to see the extended version.